# How to give more importance to one variable in a logistic regresion model?

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, modeling, feature-selection, model-selection

I'm adjusting a logistic regression model for prediction, but if the person interested says: All variables are important for me, but especially X2 is more important.

How I give that variable more value in the model or what method should I use to make the prediction?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please add some more detail on what you're doing. What does "adjusting a model" involve? In what sense is $X_2$ more important?

Comment: This has the potential to be a great question and seems like something a practicing data scientist could hear from a boss. I hope there will be an edit with additional details, even if it’s a year later.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends on what you mean by giving it more importance. If only x2 is important then leave the rest of the predictors out of the model. Or create a scale from the predictors that gives much higher weight to x2. Beyond that your question doesn't really make sense (and to  be honest, I don't know why one would want to do what I just suggested).

Unless you're a Bayesian--then I guess you should give a prior on the coefficient for x2 with mass away from zero. If you're not a Bayesian you should probably just let the data tell you which variables are more important.